# Mysql table join, but return values if first table has information, but second doesnt

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql query

```
        SELECT Name, Summoner_Name, ROUND(SUM(timePlayed)/60) as Total_Time 
                    FROM UserNames, games_database 
                    WHERE (UserNames.ID = games_database.UserNames_ID AND 
             UserNames.ID IN ({$Member_Ids_Sql}))
                    GROUP BY UserNames.ID 
                    ORDER BY Total_Time DESC;
```

It effectively will grab the players name, summoner names, and total play_time. It does this by using a table join. As one table Usernames, contains the users ID, Name and Summoner Name. Where as the Games_database table holds every game the player has played.

What I want to do is display the information of users that are in the UserNames table, but haven't played any games yet.

Extra Information:
UserNames Database contains
ID, Summoner_ID, Summoner_Name, Name

Games_database Database contains

```
ID, Match_ID, my_Date, timePlayed, champion, win, Summoner_ID, UserNames_ID, Game_Type
```

I got this working perfectly for all users with games, but when a new user enters the system, they aren't shown in this query due to no games being played.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `left join` to find non-matches:

```
SELECT Name, Summoner_Name, ROUND(SUM(timePlayed)/60) as Total_Time 
FROM UserNames LEFT JOIN
      games_database 
      ON UserNames.ID = games_database.UserNames_ID 
WHERE UserNames.ID IN ({$Member_Ids_Sql}) AND
      games_database.UserNames_ID is null
GROUP BY UserNames.ID 
ORDER BY Total_Time DESC;
```

Note:  you should learn to always use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Thank you, although that exact syntax wasn't working, i removed the and games_database.UserNames_ID is null and it worked :). Im not entirely sure of how LEFT Join works, so im off to research that. Thank you for the helping hand!

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a left outer join.  A left outer join will return all results in the first table (filleted by your where) with the results in the second table.  If there are no matches a null will be shown.

Comment: Thank you, im quite new to mysql and hadn't heard of the left join command before :)

Comment: The left join our left outer join is in almost all flavors of relational databases, here is a useful link explaining the different kind of joins http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp. It sounds like you have a cool project to start exploring databases with, best of luck. Please accept one of our answers, thanks.